# How can I change a form from within a low-level keyboard hook?

Tags: c#, winforms, static, delegates, keyboard-hook

Using the [following implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx), I have a low-level keyboard hook to detect keyboard presses from outside the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class KeyboardHook
    {
        //DLLs for global keyboard hooking
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookProc;
        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static bool ctrlPressed = false;
        
        
        public void SetHook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, _proc, hInstance, 0);
        }
        public static void UnHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }
        public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)0x100)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163)
                {
                    ctrlPressed = true;
                }
                else if (vkCode == 88 && ctrlPressed == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ctrl+x clicked");
                    //change form property ??
                }
                else
                {
                    ctrlPressed = false;
                }
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is, that I can't change form properties from within the hook.

---

I would normally instantiate the hook in my form, like so:

```
KeyboardHook hook = new KeyboardHook();
```

But in order to get my form in, I would try to pass it in the constructor

```
KeyboardHook hook = new KeyboardHook(this);
```

This would result in me making a static Form member in KeyboardHook, and assigning it to the input parameter of the constructor.  It has to be static, because all of the hook methods are static.  This does not work though, and changing properties of the Form are not observed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class KeyboardHook
    {
        //DLLs for global keyboard hooking
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = hookProc;
        private static IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static bool ctrlPressed = false;
        public static Form form; //added
        
        
        public void SetHook(Form form_in) //added
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, _proc, hInstance, 0);
            form = form_in; //added
        }
        public static void UnHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }
        public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)0x100)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163)
                {
                    ctrlPressed = true;
                }
                else if (vkCode == 88 && ctrlPressed == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ctrl+x clicked");
                    form.ChangeSomeProperty();  //this does not work
                }
                else
                {
                    ctrlPressed = false;
                }
                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
            else
                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, (int)wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

}
```

I can't pass the form in by reference either, since 'this' is read-only.
How can I change form properties inside of a low-level keyboard hook?

Comment: If you want to associate an instance of the form with an instance of the hook, I think you can just change things that are `static` but not `static extern` to be instance in your hook code. You are properly chaining to the next hook, so if you have a smallish number of hook instances in your app, it should be fine.